# Creating Generic T argument

Tags: c#, generics, syntax, arguments

Suppose I have 2 methods similar to:

```
public List<object> Do<T>(Stream stream)
{
    ...  does cool things
}

public List<object> Do(Type type, Stream stream)
{
    T = type // <- what should this be
    return Do<T>(Stream);
}
```

What is the code that allows this to operate as expected?

I imagine this question has to duplicate something on here but I couldn't find it with my google-fu.

Comment: The answer to this one pretty much suits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method.

Comment: you don't show what T is being used for

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty easy if you do it the other way around:

```
public List<object> Do<T>(Stream stream)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    Do(type, stream);
}
```

Then the other method would contain the non-duplicated logic.